# my vs code gives me an error where its says dart cannot be found in my flutter sdk

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

Could not find Dart in your Flutter SDK. Please run 'flutter doctor' in the terminal then reload the project once all issues are resolved. and when i run flutter doctor now it gives "C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

tried to rewrite the path

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to remove existing flutter sdk and download new one. Also check flutter and dart extensions are installed from VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with my VSCode so I solved it by deleting the flutter SDK folder and downloading it again now I am not facing any problems.